# Shorcut Field missing in Android Keyboard 4.3 Personal Dictionary Entries

Tags: dictionary

While trying to add entries in the Personal Dictionary,
 you first enter the phrase and then on clicking done, it asks you to enter the shortcut.

My new Xolo Q1000 Opus 2 phone has Android 4.3 and also an Android 4.3 keyboard.

However when I enter the phrase (for eg. Good Morning) and click done it does not show me the shortcut field (where I would enter the shortcut GM).

This worked perfectly well on my old phone which had Android 4.2.

Does anyone know why this is so and what is the best solution?

Please advice.

Thanks,
Sunny